# mysql queries queing (using php/mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a panel where the user would select a contact group and then schedule mail.
In order to keep a track of mails send, I am storing it into the database. 
But this storing of data in tables takes a long time as loop generates near about 1000+ insert queries which makes the page unresponsive to get the data to be populated into the table.
This is just for single user, what if at a time there are 10 users performing the same action, that would cause low performance on application.

I need to know whether is there any mechanism using 'mysql' and 'php' to que my queries so that it could be executed later and user should not wait for the query execution to be completed?

my code is as below,

```
$recordsCounter++;
//insert into EMAIL_RECIPIENTS
foreach($this->recipients as $val){         
$query="INSERT INTO bas_email_recipients SET
                recipient_type='".$val['recipientType']."', 
                email_dump_id='".$emailDumpId."', ";
        if(isset($val['contactDetailsId'])){
            $query.="contact_details_id='".$val['contactDetailsId']."', ";  
        }
        if(isset($val['contactName'])){
            $query.="recipient_name='".$val['contactName']."', ";
        }

        $query.="email_address='".$val['emailAddress']."', 
                mail_to='".$val['mailTo']."'";  

        if($db->query($query)>0){
            $recordsCounter++;
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Show your table and how you do your queries. There's a few options, like queues as you say, but mostly likely optimaztion can already be done on what you have.

Comment: It'd take me about 5 seconds to drop your entire database. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @Jonast i didn't get you?

Comment: I assume that you're receiving user input from the client, right? And I assume that you usually concatenate the input to your queries which you then run on the database, right? That means I can inject whatever I want into your queries and, for example, inject a script that drops your entire database. You can easily avoid this using prepared statements. It's funny we have "2627 How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?" as Related topics here to the right.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can put that queries into cache and retrieve/execute/remove them on cron

Instead of

```
if($db->query($query)>0){ // putting to database
    $recordsCounter++;
}
```

Put query to array

```
$queryList[] = $query;
```

and then put this array to cache with some unique key:

```
$cache->put('key', $queryList);
```

Install cron job for say every minute to execute:

```
$queryList = $cache->get('key');
if ($queryList) {
    foreach ($queryList as $query) {
        $db->query($query);
    }
}
```

Heavy database operations will be executed in cron in background, so you will get much better performance with your web

Comment: @Andrey can u clarify it using any example?

Comment: Show me your existing code and I will change it according to my idea

Comment: @Andrey check I have udpated the question with the code.

Comment: I'm not getting how to use cache operation as I'm newbie to it.

Comment: Is there any tut of can u explain how to use the cache operation?

Comment: Google it yourself please. Using cache is very popular and you will get enought info about it for sure.